# MRTK 2.4 - ScrollingObjectCollection not updating via script

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I created a notification panel in my scene, that shows notifications when something happens. Those notifications are just buttons that get added as children to the `ScrollingObjectCollection`:
[image]

The issue that I have, is that after deleting one notification (that one in the middle) the collection gets not updated. But clicking in the inspector on the `UpdateCollection`-Btn will update the collection. I debugged and saw that it is aware that after deleting one, only two notifications are left.

```
private void DeleteNotification()
{
    if (NotifyManager.Instance.RemoveNotificationFromList(Id))
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        NotifyManager.Instance.ScrollingCollection.UpdateCollection();
    }
}
```

[image]

 This is what the button `UpdateCollection` from the `ScrollingObjectCollection` in the Inspector calls and its the same method that I'm calling too:

```
if (GUILayout.Button("Update Collection"))
{
    scrollContainer.UpdateCollection();
    EditorUtility.SetDirty(scrollContainer);
}
```

Does somebody know how to update that collection on runtime via code?

My setup:

- Unity 2019.4.18
- MRTK 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it by myself. The problem was that all happend in one frame and the `ScrollingObjectCollection` was not in a state where the notification was deleted. So I created another method in my NotifyManager where I wait for the end of the frame and then call `UpdateCollection`.

```
private IEnumerator WaitBeforeUpdateCollection()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    scrollingCollection.UpdateCollection();
}
```